# Each time I build my Android app (running on phone), I lose disk space

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been developing an Android app for a week using Android Studio. I've noticed my disk space has been dropping and I don't know why. It seems that each time I run the app (99% of the time I use a test device, not an emulator), I lose disk space on my computer's hard drive. I have no idea why. Does anyone else know why and how I can fix it?

Update 2021: I had forgotten that I asked this question but someone else is having the same problem. I never figured this out on my old laptop. I ended up only working on my desktop (which didn't have this problem). Sorry I can't be more help :/

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `Build->Clean Project` and then `Build->Rebuild Project`, it will reduce the space occupied by your project folder.

As for the rest, a good portion of the space occupied by Android Studio comes from the packages you have downloaded within the SDK manager. Try uninstalling those you don't currently need to free some space on your HD. See if it helps.

Comment: That's not solving it. I've cleaned and rebuilt the project multiple times. Honestly, each time I run the app on my phone, another 5mb or so of storage space on my computer is eaten up. I thought I was storing logs, but the log file isn't growing.